# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'sample' was corrupted

Tags: c++, stack

I have this array, I was trying strncat and I got this error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'sample' was corrupted.

```
char sample[] = "red";
char * y = "blue";


cout << strncat(sample, y, sizeof(sample));
```

It does executes strncat correctly, but after exiting the main function, Run-time check failure occurs.

**EDIT:
just add size to the destination character array to solve this!**

```
char sample[10] = "red";
    char * y = "blue";


    cout << strncat(sample, y, sizeof(y));
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no space in `sample` to append the string `y`.

Also, you seem to misunderstood what the third parameter of [`strncat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) is. It's not the size of the destination (1st parameter) but the amount of characters from the source (2nd parameter) to append.

Try this instead:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    //   space for red  space for blue   space for zero
    //          ^        ^                ^
    char sample[3     +  4              + 1] = "red";
    const char* y = "blue";
    //                           number of chars in y
    //                               ^
    std::cout << strncat (sample, y, strlen (y)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I changed my 3rd parameter to sizeof(y), yet still got the run time error

Comment: @chrisjohn016 that gives you the size of a pointer which is also wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just add size to the destination character array to solve this!

```
char sample[10] = "red";
    char * y = "blue";


    cout << strncat(sample, y, sizeof(y));
```

Comment: This is incorrect code. sizeof(y) == sizeof(char*) == 4 bytes on x86 system (or 8 bytes on x64 and so on), so only 4/8 symbols would be copied. You should use strlen instead.